# how to disable the selection container on pressing back button in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack

```
           SelectionContainer {
                Text(
                    text = message.text,
                    style = TextStyle(
                        color = Color.Black,
                        fontSize = 15.sp
                    ),
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(
                        vertical = 4.dp,
                        horizontal = 10.dp
                    ),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = Color.White,
                )
            }
```

in here when the back button is pressed i want to make the selected text unselected

I wanted to deselect the selected text on the back button pressed nut don't know how to do it

Comment: I think its not possible you need to find other way to accomplish.